# how to make a button of free shape?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button

I want to create map app. For example, the are different areas in Japan. All of them are different shape, not square. You push on it and it gonna change the color. It is possible to create the button of unusual form (the form of region on the map) in Xcode?

Comment: All views are rectangular, and buttons are too, since they are views. But, getting notified about the touch inside the area of unusual form is possible. Please clarify if you need to show that area highlighted when user presses on it?

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk Thank you for response. For example, you have 6 areas: like Osaka prefecture, Kyoto prefecture and so on. And you want to show on the screen that you have already been there by pushing on that area. That area should change color from clear to green. So I realize that buttons are just blue print, but how to make that push response only inside prefecture area, not neighbor area.

Answer (score 2):

**Drawing**

In order to draw the custom shape on the map, use your custom subclass of `MKPolygon` where you'll define your selected state color, and `selected` flag.

```
internal final class MyPolygon: MKPolygon {
   internal var selected = false
   internal var selectedColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.6)

   ...   
}
```

In order to draw a custom color for your custom `MKPolygon`, create your subclass of `MKPolygonRenderer`  and use custom drawing to fill the polygon with the `selectedColor` when it has `selected == true`.

When those two implemented, add your overlay onto `MKMapView`

```
mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
```

Assign the `delegate` to your `mapView`, and return your renderer for the polygon from the delegate's method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let polygon = overlay as? MyPolygon {
        return MyPolygonRenderer(polygon: polygon)
    }
    return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
}
```

**Catching user input**

Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` onto your `mapView`:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapViewDidTap(_:)))
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    ...
}

func mapViewDidTap(_ tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if tapRecognizer.state == .recognized {
        // Get map coordinate from touch point
        let touchCoord = tapRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
        let coord = mapView.convert(touchCoord, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        let coordRect = MKMapRect(origin: coord, size: MKMapSize())
        // for every overlay ...
        for overlay in mapView.overlays {
            // .. if MyPolygon ...
            if let polygon = overlay as? MyPolygon {
                let selected = polygon.intersects(coordRect)
                if polygon.selected != selected {
                    polygon.selected = selected
                    mapView.renderer(for: polygon)?.setNeedsDisplay()
                }
            }
        }      
    }
}
```